# Silence output in bash script using function advisable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, io-redirection

Suppose, someone is writing bash script in which it is needed to silent stdout,stderr and provide custom output.

Is it advisable to use function like below:

```
dump(){
    "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

And, then

```
dump rm filename || echo "custom-message"
```

What are the possible cases where it fails to function as expected?

Comment: Are you expecting the `echo` to be silenced by `dump` as well? It won't be.

Comment: @chepner: You mean that of "custom-message"? No, that should be displayed.
Generally, I prefer to use some function instead of echo that take argument and do echo over those arguments and then exit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good technique. I use something like it all the time. Pros:

- Preserves the exit code of the command.
- Hides output of almost every program unless they directly write to `/dev/tty` or `/dev/console`, which is rare and probably for good reason anyways.
- Works on shell builtins just as well as binaries. You can use this for `cd`, `pushd`/`popd`, etc.
- Doesn't stop the command from reading from stdin. `dump` can be used at the end of a pipeline if you wish.
- `"$@"` properly handles command names and arguments with whitespace, globs, and other special characters.

It looks good to me!

The only nitpick I have is that the name `dump` isn't the clearest.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What function name would you suggest?

Comment: `quiet` or `silent` perhaps.